# how to upgrade go mod to v2 or higher version?

Tags: go

My go package version is v1.0.7 and now I want to upgrade it to v2.0.0. I create a new tag with it bug when I use `go get CODEPATH` it still use version v1.0.7. The go.mod should like `require CODEPATH v2.0.0+incompatible` but I want to know what command will do this?

The document [Modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#releasing-modules-v2-or-higher) says that add /v2 to module path but didn't tell how to upgrade client's go.mod.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ivan.corrales.solera/migrating-to-go-mod-in-just-3-steps-6b6a07a04640

Comment: Note that the import path changes as well for upgrades of the major version. It should be now `CODEPATH/v2`

Comment: @Henry I tried to add /v2 but with the `go get` command the go.mod seems to change to v2.0.0

Answer (score 6):

I tried myself and it worked.

1. Add `/v2` to your go.mod's module line `module github.com/mnhkahn/aaa/v2`;
2. If you import a sub-package of the module, import like this `import "github.com/mnhkahn/aaa/v2/config"`;
3. Create a tag with name v2.0.0;
4. `go get github.com/mnhkahn/aaa/v2`;
5. `go mod tidy`;

Answer (score 3):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55119729/11210494) from Bryce looks good if you are doing this manually.

If you are interested in an automated approach (for example, perhaps you have many files you would need to visit), a good automated solution is https://github.com/marwan-at-work/mod, which can automatically add, remove, or change the required `/vN` in your `*.go` code and your `go.mod`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55189901/11210494) for more details.